# How to convert the equation of a line from polar to standard form?

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

How do you convert a polar line to a line in standard form? That being, change a line with parameters $\rho$ and $\theta$ in a polar coordinate system, to a standard form ($Ax+By=C$) in Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: You mean like this? http://www.analyzemath.com/polarcoordinates/polar_to_rectangular_eq.html

Comment: A *straight* line or something more general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In even more general cases than converting a line to and from polar, you can use the substitutions
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right), x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$$
Note that because $\arctan$ only takes values in $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, the identity given for $\theta$ doesn't do all the work: you need to decide between the fourth and the second, and between the first and the third, quadrants based on the signs of $x$ and $y$.